# Cannot install paperclip 2.5.0 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

All environment was set up from railsinstaller.
Ruby - 1.9.2-p290
Rails - 3.1.1 etc

Error:
G:\Projects\burk>gem install paperclip -v '2.5.0'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-2.5.0/test/fixtures/question?mark.png

Version 2.4.5 installed fine, but got error on migrate:

G:\Projects\burk>gem install paperclip -v '2.5.0' --trace
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --trace

G:\Projects\burk>rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  CreateBrands: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:brands)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Tab
leDefinition:0x5c804a0>
G:/Projects/burk/db/migrate/20120115082718_create_brands.rb:6:in`block in ch
ange'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:161:in `create_table
'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:481:in`create_table'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:447:in `block in method_missing'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:422:in`block in say_with_time'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:422:in`say_with_time'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:442:in `method_missing'
G:/Projects/burk/db/migrate/20120115082718_create_brands.rb:3:in`change'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:391:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in`measure'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:391:in `block in migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in`with_connectio
n'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:375:in `migrate'
C:in`migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:687:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:744:in`call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:744:in `ddl_transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:686:in`block in migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:671:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:671:in`migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:549:in `up'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:530:in`migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:161:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:205:in`call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:200:in`each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:200:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:158:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:151:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:116:in`invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in`each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in`standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:66:in`block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:63:in`run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
 `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in`load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:19:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that someone added a file named `question?mark.png` to the Gem test files to test Paperclip's behaviour with such file names. Unfortunately question marks are not legal characters for file names in Windows. (See [directory](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree/master/test/fixtures), commit [history](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commits/master/test/fixtures) and [discussion](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/621) and [issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/703))

<s>The best workaround for this is to download the [zip file from Github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/downloads), copy it into your project and explicitly reference the Gem from your Gemfile like this:</s>

```
gem 'paperclip', path: 'vendor/gems/paperclip'
```

**EDIT:** As or version 2.5.2 the Paperclip gem can be installed again on Windows platform. ([Commit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/ed5cd9f192953278a27efa82976c21d78cea9e8f))